# While setting up new SPFX environment getting Error of unsupportability

Tags: sharepoint-online, spfx, spfx-webparts, modern-experience, spfx-tooling

I am trying to set up an environment for SPFX development. I tried to install the latest version of nodejs.

I installed latest version of nodejs 14.15.4 and automatically npm verion 6.14.11 installed.

Then installed
"npm install -g yo gulp" successfully.But while installing "npm install -g @microsoft/generator-sharepoint" got below error:

```
C:\SPFX>npm install -g @microsoft/generator-sharepoint
npm WARN deprecated resolve-url@0.2.1: https://github.com/lydell/resolve-url#deprecated
npm WARN deprecated urix@0.1.0: Please see https://github.com/lydell/urix#deprecated
npm WARN deprecated request@2.88.2: request has been deprecated, see https://github.com/request/request/issues/3142
npm WARN deprecated axios@0.18.1: Critical security vulnerability fixed in v0.21.1. For more information, see https://github.com/axios/axios/pull/3410
npm WARN deprecated har-validator@5.1.5: this library is no longer supported
npm WARN notsup Unsupported engine for got@5.7.1: wanted: {"node":">=0.10.0 <7"} (current: {"node":"14.15.4","npm":"6.14.11"})
npm WARN notsup Not compatible with your version of node/npm: got@5.7.1

+ @microsoft/generator-sharepoint@1.11.0
updated 1 package in 9.888s
```

Now if I try to create new SPFX project using command "yo @microsoft/sharepoint" then simply nothing is getting created inside the project folder.

Kindly help me to resolve this. Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

SPFX currently support Node.js 10.x and not supported Node.js 14.x, please uninstall the Node.js and reinstall Node.js 10.X version here:

[Index of /dist/latest-v10.x/](https://nodejs.org/dist/latest-v10.x/)

Answer (score 2):

You need the earlier version of Node.js, v14.x is not supported for SPFx.
I've set up with v10.22 on my machine and it works.

For more information see MS Article [Install Node js](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/sharepoint/dev/spfx/set-up-your-development-environment)

Answer (score 0):

Node.js v14.x is not supported for SharePoint Framework development.

You need to use version **v10.x.x** (if you're developing solutions for SharePoint Server 2019 or **SharePoint Online** - Recommended for your case

OR v8.x.x (if you're developing solutions for **SharePoint Server 2016**)

---

At this time, Node.js v14.x is the Active LTS version listed on the Node.js homepage as the default download. To download Node.js v10.x, use the [Node.js > Downloads > Previous Releases](https://nodejs.org/en/download/releases/) page.

---

I will strongly recommend you to follow the Microsoft documentation given below to set up the development environment. This is very detailed and useful guide:

[Set up your SharePoint Framework development environment](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/sharepoint/dev/spfx/set-up-your-development-environment)